# RHEL7 kickstart fails to contact nfs server

Tags: rhel, nfs, kickstart

I have a situation where the target host is RHEL 5.x and I have to kickstart it to fresh RHEL7.9. no other option, but only ks. and KS is not working. :-(

**target host**: (this range is allowed to ping,mount etc. from KS server). DL 380 G6 (Two HP NC382i dual port multifunction gigabit server adapters (Four eth ports total) with TCP/IP OffloadEngine, including support for Accelerated iSCSI). I am now doubting if this is supported in RHEL7 or not...

```
addr: 130.110.160.20
mask: 255.255.255.128
gway: 130.110.160.1
```

**KS server**: KS server is RHEL 5.11. running dhcp, nfs etc.

```
addr: 130.110.170.30
mask: 255.255.255.128
nfs is ON, shares are mountable. following are nfs shares:
/home/rhel7 ====> has loop mounted rhel 7 iso
/home/ksconfig/ks-myhost-cfg  =============> my ks config file (generated using online RH tool)
```

I boot the target host using remote mounted RHEL 7 DVD. At the 'isntall' screen, I press tab, and I am giving following options. But when i run tcpdump on KS server, I see nothing. seems it is not even reaching out to NFS server....

```
vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=RHEL-7.9 Server.x86_64 ks=nfs:130.110.170.30:/home/ksconfig/130.110.160.20-kickstart ksdevice=eth0 ip=ens1:dhcp repo=nfs:130.110.170.30:/home/rhel7 quiet inst.text
```

I also tried:

```
vmlinuz initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=RHEL-7.9 Server.x86_64 ks=nfs:130.110.170.30:/home/ksconfig/130.110.160.20-kickstart ksdevice=eth0 ip=130.110.160.20 netmask=255.255.255.128 gateway=130.110.160.1 repo=nfs:130.110.170.30:/home/rhel7 quiet inst.text
```

and many more....

**i just dont see any traffic coming to nfs server in tcpdump...**

```
ks-server# tcpdump -vv -s 0 -i eth0 host 130.110.160.20
....nothing....
```

errors out with:

dracut-initqueue: Warning: Could not boot.
and drops into dracut shell.

by the way this is the content of ISO share on KS server.

```
[root@ks-server~]# ls -ltr /home/rhel7
total 974
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   3211 Jul 14  2020 RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   3375 Jul 14  2020 RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-beta
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  18092 Sep 17  2020 GPL
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   1455 Sep 17  2020 extra_files.json
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   8266 Sep 17  2020 EULA
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    114 Sep 17  2020 media.repo
-r--r--r-- 1 root root   1796 Sep 17  2020 TRANS.TBL
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root   2048 Sep 17  2020 repodata
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 946176 Sep 17  2020 Packages
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root   2048 Sep 17  2020 LiveOS
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root   2048 Sep 17  2020 isolinux
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root   2048 Sep 17  2020 images
dr-xr-xr-x 3 root root   2048 Sep 17  2020 EFI
dr-xr-xr-x 4 root root   2048 Sep 17  2020 addons
```

Comment: What network adapter is on the host that you are trying to kickstart? I ran into an issue where the e1000e driver included with RHEL7 did not support the newer version of the intel I219-LM network adapter on a workstation I was building. I believe the symptoms were similar to what you're seeing.

Comment: Hi, target host has 4 eth ports. DL 380 G6  (Two HP NC382i dual port multifunction gigabit server adapters (Four ports total) with TCP/IP OffloadEngine, including support for Accelerated iSCSI)

Comment: That hardware is old enough that I do not think you would be seeing exactly the same situation as I ran into. However, it could still fall under the 'unsupported hardware' category for Red Hat. In my situation I was PXE booting. The host could send out the DHCP and even download the initrd image, as soon as the initrd loaded up, it would also load up the driver for the NIC (e1000e in my case), which did not support the version of the NIC in the workstation and it would lose all network connectivity. My solution was to add a newer version of the driver to the initrd as well as the actual build.

Comment: thank you. i am trying to confirm if NIC is the issue.